# Why does the canplaythrough event only fire when I console.log(this) in the emptied event?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, dom-events

My JavaScript doesn’t load audio files all the time unless I use `console.log` on the audio object.

I have code that loads an audio file and plays it.

```
var sound;

sound = new Audio("foo.mp3");
sound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    //Do stuff
});
```

The `canplaythrough` event doesn’t fire every single time (I assume this means it hasn’t loaded enough to allow the event to fire). Since I’m using this in a small game preloader, I’m relying on the event to fire before letting the game run.

During testing I used `console.log` to inspect the `sound` object when the following events are fired: `emptied`, `loadedmetadata`, `loadeddata`, `canplay`, and of course `canplaythrough`.

```
sound.addEventListener("emptied", function(){
    console.log(this);
});

// the same for loadedmetadata, loadeddata, and canplay events
```

If I use `console.log` on any of the properties of the `this` object (for example `console.log(this.readyState)`) there is no noticeable change.

Strangely, though, as long as I use `console.log` on the `this` object in the `emptied` event listener, I can’t reproduce this bug; the files seem to load every time.

Why is this? By using `console.log`, am I forcing the file to load or something?

Example of code in use.

```
function preloader(){
    var sound, onemptied, oncanplaythrough;

    onemptied = function(){
        console.log(this); // I would like to omit this
        sound.removeEventListener("emptied", onemptied);
    };

    oncanplaythrough = function(){
        window.sound = sound;
        sound.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", oncanplaythrough);
        loadGame();
    };

    sound = new Audio("foo.mp3");
    sound.addEventListener("emptied", onemptied);
    sound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", oncanplaythrough);
    sound.load();
}

function loadGame(){
    sound.load();
    sound.play();
}
```

Comment: Can you check stalled, suspend and ended? I'm not entirely sure without seeing the rest of the code, can you make sure there's nothing else in the call stack that could be interfering with the audio playback? Is the start of the audio playback deferred or is there something else going on at the same time?

Comment: I've tried debugging using the code

    
    sound.addEventListener("eventname", function(){
      console.log(url + " eventname");
    });

but with the following events: `abort`, `canplay`, `durationchange`, `emptied`, `ended`, `error`, `loadeddata`, `loadedmetadata`, `loadstart`, `pause`, `play`, `playing`, `progress`, `ratechange`, `seeked`, `seeking`, `stalled`, `suspend`, `timeupdate`, `volumechange`, `waiting`, and `canplaythrough`.

The only events that run when the load fails seem to be `emptied`, and `loadstart`.

I've also updated my post to show the `play()` function is deferred.